# Bulk Insert not being saved to database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have the following method. After execution is complete, there is no data in my database table. **And no exceptions are being thrown/swallowed.** The strange thing is if I cut and paste the query string into SSMS and execute it, the script executes and there is data in the table. Is there any reason why this isn't working from .NET?

```
static void ImportTableData(String tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        @"Server=MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER;Database=MY_DATABASE;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        String schemaOwner = tableName.Substring(0, 3);

        const String sqlScript =
            @"BULK
            INSERT {0}
            FROM 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\{1}\{0}.csv'
            WITH
            (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
                FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\{1}\{0}.xml',
                DATAFILETYPE='native'
            )";

        String realQuery = String.Format(sqlScript, tableName, schemaOwner);
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(realQuery, connection, tran))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And the content of `realQuery` is:

```
BULK
INSERT SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE
FROM 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\SCHEMA\SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\SCHEMA\SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE.xml',
    DATAFILETYPE='native'
)
```

**EDIT**

I tried writing the realQuery variable to a sql file. If I execute this from SSMS the data is inserted. If I execute the sql file from .NET the data is not inserted. It is the same exact script being executed through both ways.

```
String realQuery = String.Format(sqlScript, tableName, schemaOwner);
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\temp.sql", new[] { realQuery });
String script = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\temp.sql").ReadToEnd();

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, connection, tran))
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your field terminator is `' + CHAR(9) + '`? And are there any errors? You aren't swallowing them, are you?

Comment: Yes - if I cut and paste this script directly into SSMS and run it the data is inserted. So it seems that the issue may be in the C# code.

Comment: How would you directly paste it? This SQL string has placeholders. Please add the exact SQL that you executed in SSMS.

Comment: Well, that field terminator is completely wrong. I doubt that this works. Or, is the terminator not being used with a format file?

Comment: Those formats were for `\t` and `\r\n`. I changed in the code (edit reflected) and the issue is still remaining. I'm mostly wondering if I did something wrong with the SqlCommand or SqlTransaction/connection. Could it be that the string is stored as `BULK\r\n                    INSERT SCHEMA.TABLE\r\n                    FROM `

Comment: Do you get an exception after the ExecuteNonQuery() is called?  You should probably use char(9) for the tab delimeter, and char(13) + char(10) for the \r\n.  Try that

Comment: @Mangist - I've tried that as well but it does not work from .NET. I made this switch but the insert was still not in the database. Ideally I'd like to use Query Analyzer but I don't have it installed on this box.

Comment: Honestly, this looks more like a confusion than a technical error. Maybe the wrong path, wrong server, wrong database, ... The code is fine. Actually, best-practice.

Comment: Not working means...? Does it throw exception? Also, HLGEM recommendation is good to consider.

Answer (score 1):

First run profiler and see exactly what was sent to the database by the application. You may see the problem then.

Also in context of being sent from the application would the the database have access to to your personal c:drive or would it be looking at the database server's c:drive? Generally I never use a personal location but rather one o the server I am using.

Comment: SQL Profile capture looks correct meaning that what is being sent to the server is exactly what is supposed to be sent. When I cut and paste to SSMS and run it the rows are inserted. That is a good point about the execution server - but I am running SQL Server and this application on the same box. I will update if I can find any more information.

Comment: That was it - I moved it to the `C:\ ` root directory and it was able to load everything correctly. I guess that the application couldn't access the `C:\users\ ` folder but I don't understand why yet. It's strange. I will look into this and if I find a more complete answer I will post a solution.

Comment: @IanO'Brien are you using a Windows user? SQL Server impersonates that user (unfortunately). The more important question: Why did you not notice the exception that surely was triggered when SQL Server could not access that file?

Comment: @usr Could the exceptions not be bubbling up from SQL Server? There is nothing in the script to handle exceptions so I don't know if they're even getting passed back into the application. It's simply and only the `BULK INSERT` statement. I have catch all unhandled exceptions turned on and I have a `try/catch` with a breakpoint and nothing is getting hit.

Comment: @IanO'Brien turn on "break on all exceptions" to find out for sure. Also, test error handling by executing `select 0/0`.